# Unable to connect Galaxy Tab 10.1 to Windows 7 for transferring files

Tags: samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I am unable to connect a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 to a computer via included cable. Here is what I tried:

- Tried to mount on Windows XP (32), Windows 7 (32), Windows 7(64), and OSX (Snow Leopard).
- Tried installing official drivers from US and CANADA Samsung website.
- Tried installing several versions of Kies.
- Tried installing driver through each version of Kies.
- Tried to see/push to device in DDMS using Eclipse with latest Android SDK.
- Tried to connect using Odin, but I do not get any device information.
- Tried installing drivers from other websites.
- Tried Android File Transer for OS X.

None of these seem to work and after two weeks, I really have no other ideas of what to try. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called Customer Support and it sounded like a defective unit. They covered it under the 1 yr included warranty. They pay for the shipping label as well, all you need to supply is the box.